# Global variables in Python across all modules

Tags: python, module, global-variables, python-module

I am currently working on a game project in Python, and I find myself struggling with the "concepts" behind Python as I'm used to languages such as C or Java.

I have tried to "divide" my project in several files (that are called modules if I'm not mistaken, although they are all in the same folder as I would do with C source files) with different themes : `objects.py`, `map.py`, `rendering.py`, etc. They contain different classes and functions related to these notions. I have a `main.py` that contains all my "main" functions (such as `new_game` and so on) as well as the first "call", that will call `main_menu`.

I also have a `constants.py` file where I store constant values. Now the thing is, I have several "global" variables and objects in my game : the player object, the map, and so on. I wish to keep these variables global across all modules and be able to access and modify them from everywhere.

I first created a `global_variables.py` file where I listed all my variables (such as `map = None`, `player = None`, etc), expecting to modify them via other modules.

The problem is, each time I called import `global_variables` again, it ran through the whole code and reinitialized all of them to `None`, which I obviously do not want.

I read on another stackoverflow thread a tip: creating a `init()` function in my file where I would initialize all variables and declare them global. This way, I call `global_variables.init()` once, and then I can simply do `global_variables.player` to access the player and modify it.

It works well, but I find it cluttered. I have a ton of `global foo`, followed by `foo = None` and it feels like unnecessary lines of code. Furthermore, IDEs can't "access" the variables, when I type global_variables. , it does not suggest the variables as autocomplete, which is quite a pain.

So is there another way of doing so? The idea would be to "declare" the variables out of any function so that the IDEs understand they're there, but only "initialize" them once so that I avoid them being reset each time I import the `global_variables` module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The problem is, each time I called import global_variables again, it ran through the whole code and reinitialized all of them to None, which I obviously do not want.

No, Python will not re-run the code when you import that module multiple times. A module is executed just *once*, producing a module object that then is reused for subsequent imports.

As such, using a module for all your program globals is fine. Just make sure you import the module and assign back to attributes on that module object:

```
import global_variables

global_variables.name = 'Inigo Montoya'
```

and any other module that imports `global_variables` will see `global_variables.name` as set to `'Inigo Montoya'`. No `init()` function required.

Do *not* use `from global_variables import name`, because that creates a new name `name` in your module that won't see any new values if other code rebinds `global_variables.name` to a different value.

Comment: Then I don't understand. I imported global_variables as gv and had a function that would, for example, initialize gv.map with a double for loop (as it simulated a 2 dimensions array). Then I would call another function, from there, that was in another module to act on map, and it would show me that map = None. So no change was made to map. And I had found the init() solution as an answer to that problem, that other people encountered.

Comment: @lap0573: you need to use `import global_variables`, *not* `from global_variables import map`; the latter would still be bound to the previous value if `global_variables.map` was changed.

Comment: @lap0573: in Python, all names (attributes, locals, globals) and items in lists, tuples, sets and dictionaries, etc. are *references*. If you rebind such a name, other names that reference the old object won't be rebound to the new object. By using `modulename.name` you always refer to the one attribute (a global name in that module) and always see what that was bound to.

Comment: Oh indeed ! That is what I was doing at this time, hence the issue. I just quickly tried taking everything out of init() and importing as you said, and everything works smoothly. Thanks a lot :)